# Electric field between the inner surface of a hollow conducting sphere, and a point charge inside it

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, symmetry, conductors

In the image bellow, I'm not considering the "walls" of the conductor, but rather the vacuum that exists between the point charge inside and the inner surface of the conductor. Is the electric field zero there? I know it is zero inside the walls but what about that free space?

[image]

Comment: Hello! I have taken the liberty to [resize your image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25051/) to improve readability. Feel free to rollback if you wish. Thanks!

Comment: This is discussed in griffiths and many times in this site

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/617489/